# How to send email to submitter in a webform?

Tags: webforms, emails, forms

I have a webform and i want to send by mail this webform to submitter.
For the moment, i created an hidden field with token [current-user:mail] and i chose this field in adress.
I think it isn't very well. Can I do it in hook_form_alter ? if yes, how to do it?

Comment: I think you can use Rules and Webform Rules module in combination to send mail, which drupal version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a e-mail field in the webform, whether it is hidden or not is up to you. You should then set the current users e-mail address as the default value. For this, you will need hook_form_alter()

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //drupal_set_message($form_id); (uncomment this to get form id)
  if ($form_id == 'your_webform_id') { 
    global user;
    if ( $user->uid ) { //check user is logged in
    $form['field_email']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $user->mail;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have a solution to send email without use of field in webform ?

Comment: Would the webform submitter always be logged in? Otherwise you wouldnt have the email of an anonymous user

Comment: yes, the webform submitter who is logged in.

Comment: Try installing https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules and rules, and create a rule for "after webform is submitted" to send to the current user who submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In Drupal 8 you can go to webform settings-> email/handler -> add email then select current user email address for **To email**.